# TFS Pipline for multi projects

Tags: tfs, ssis

We have several SSIS project(solution) which are in main folder in TFS. notice each solution is in related sub-folder. we are going to provide release pipeline in current TFS, I am going to create three branches: DEV, MAIN and RELEASE, however I have the following question:

Since the ssis projects (solutions) are developed and have been updating with different team and release in different times, should I create the mentioned branches ( DEV, MAIN and RELEASE) for each ssis project(solution) separately? or I have to create global branches  ( DEV, MAIN and RELEASE) ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each set of code/projects that is released together should live in the same branch.  If you have projects or sets of projects that are developed and released separately, it makes sense to have separate sets of branches.

Comment: Thanks Dylan for your answer. I am going to create DEV, MAIN and RELEASE branch/folder for each solution, and then move the current solution to related DEV Branch/Folder. Am I in correct way? Thanks, Bruce